# Redirigir urls por cambio a urls amigables

Tags: wordpress, redirección

se me ocurrió remplazar las urls de mis páginas por urls amigables, así que eliminé la parte de la fecha de las URLs, eso me trajo el problema de que la autoridad de mi sitio descendió.

¿Cómo puedo agregar una redirección del antiguo formato de URLs al nuevo?

Antiguo formato:

http://javapro.org/blog/2016/09/30/como-solucionar-error-de-bios-laptop-lenovo

Nuevo formato:

http://javapro.org/blog/como-solucionar-error-de-bios-laptop-lenovo/

## Intentos

Mediante el pligin [SEO Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/) escribí la siguiente regla

Desde `Regex`: `\/blog(\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})(\/[a-zA-Z\-]+\/)`
Hacia `Página`: `/blog$2`

Esta regla nunca se activó.

Posteriormente intenté con:

Desde `Regex`: `/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/(.*)`
Hacia `Página`: `/blog/$1`

Lo cual me lleva siempre al mismo post

Comment: Por si alguien ocupa pedí soporte acá: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/friendly-urls-redirect/#new-topic-0

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser a través de `enlaces permanentes`, en el ajuste de `Mes y nombre`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso es exactamente lo que hice, ahora los sitios que tenían las urls con fecha que apuntaban a mi sitio me dan 404 porque la url con fecha ya no existe